# Substring between first instance of two different symbols

Tags: java, string

I want to parse the following and store it as a new string, with the condition that `mawi` is stored and everything else is removed.

```
<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>
```

One solution I suppose could be a substring starting with the first character after the first `>` and ending two characters before the first `-`. All the data is identical. The result is a String with value `mawi`.

```
 String initial = "<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>";
 String substring = initial.substring(example.indexOf(">"));
```

Not sure where to go from here... Any thoughts?

Comment: You are paring XML? If yes use an XML parser

Comment: SubstringBefore/SubstringAfter/SubstringBetween - substring extraction relative to other strings : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So now you got `substring` which is equal to: `>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>`.

Now, you can substring your substring again to find only **mawi**, like this;

```
String initial = "<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>";
String midSub = initial.substring(initial.indexOf('>'));
String finalSub = midSub.substring(1, midSub.indexOf(' ')); // 1 because we still have `>`
System.out.println(finalSub);
```

Or, one liner:

```
String finalSub = initial.substring(initial.indexOf('>')+1, initial.indexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 3):

Although the below   code do the trick, I suggest you to use Jsoup or XML Parse if you are processing multiple strings like this

```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<ns0:Assignee>(.+?)</ns0:Assignee>");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>");
  matcher.find();
  String result = matcher.group(1);
  String finalString = result.split(" - ")[0];
  System.out.println(finalString); // mawi
```

Comment: This `(.+?)` won't work if there is a line break between the two substrings. Add a `Pattern.DOTALL` flag.

Answer (score 2):

If all the strings are built like your example string, you could go with this:

```
initial.substring(initial.indexOf('>') + 1, initial.indexOf(' '));
```

Note the `+ 1` at the start index.

When your Strings are more complicated, I would recommend either using a library for working with XML or using Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1):

show this:

```
String s = "<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>";
s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<ns0:Assignee>")+"<ns0:Assignee>".length(), s.indexOf("</ns0:Assignee>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class string {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

     String s = "<ns0:Assignee>mawi - Manfred Wilson</ns0:Assignee>";
     s = s.substring(14, 18);
     System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```